# by operator does not work when combined with [_n] and [_n-1]

Tags: stata

In my dataset the variable **dyrstr** is supposed to have the same value for every **firm_id** as is the case in the following:

```
firm_id year    dyrstr
1   1975    1974
1   1976    1974
1   1977    1974
1   1978    1974
1   1979    1974
3   1975    1941
3   1976    1941
3   1977    1941
3   1978    1941
3   1979    1941
4   1975    1963
4   1976    1963
4   1977    1963
4   1978    1963
4   1979    1963
```

To check whether this is also true in the rest of the dataset I want to create a variable which equals 1 if, regarding a single **firm_id**, **dyrstr** has more than one value.

My code looks like this:

```
sort firm_id year
by firm_id: gen twodyrstr = 1 if (dyrstr[_n-1] != dyrstr[_n])
```

Unfortunately, in this context, `by firm_id` doesn't seem to work as **twodyrstr** equals 1 if the **firm_id** changes which is of course not what I want. 
In the following you can see the result of my code:

```
firm_id year   dyrstr   twodyrstr
1   1975    1974    1
1   1976    1974    
1   1977    1974    
1   1978    1974    
1   1979    1974    
3   1975    1941    1
3   1976    1941    
3   1977    1941    
3   1978    1941    
3   1979    1941    
4   1975    1963    1
4   1976    1963    
4   1977    1963    
4   1978    1963    
4   1979    1963
```

No value for **twodyrstr** means that there is a missing value.
Why does my code not work? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stata is doing exactly what you are asking it to do: for each `firm_id`, 
compare the current observation with the previous one and set the new variable
to 1 if they are different. This only occurs for every first observation because
it is compared with `.` (missing) which is a "very high number" in Stata.

A different strategy is to check if, after a `sort`, the first and last observations coincide for each firm:

```
clear all
set more off

input firm_id year    dyrstr
1   1975    1974
1   1976    1974
1   1977    1974
1   1978    1974
1   1979    1974
3   1975    1941
3   1976    1941
3   1977    1941
3   1978    1941
3   1979    1941
4   1975    1963
4   1976    1963
4   1977    1963
4   1978    1966
4   1979    1963
end

bysort firm_id (dyrstr): gen twodyrstr = (dyrstr[1] == dyrstr[_N])

list, sepby(firm_id)
```

Notice the sorting is by `firm_id dyrstr`, but the right-hand side of the command is executed by `firm_id` only. This is achieved enclosing `dyrstr` between parenthesis in the left-hand side.

If you have missings and all other non-missing values are equal to each other, you will not get 1's because a missing is sorted to the last place, compared with a non-missing, and that evaluates to false (0). One way of avoiding this is:

```
clear all
set more off

input firm_id year    dyrstr
1   1975    1974
1   1976    1974
1   1977    1974
1   1978    1974
1   1979    1974
3   1975    1941
3   1976    1941
3   1977    1941
3   1978    1941
3   1979    1941
4   1975    .
4   1976    1963
4   1977    .
4   1978    1963
4   1979    1963
end

* Do not destroy original; make a copy
generate dyrstrmiss = dyrstr
* Sort
sort firm_id dyrstrmiss
* "Extrapolate" if missing
replace dyrstrmiss = dyrstrmiss[_n-1] if missing(dyrstrmiss)
* Compare first with last
bysort firm_id: gen twodyrstr = (dyrstrmiss[1] == dyrstrmiss[_N])

list, sepby(firm_id)
```

Firm 4 has a **unique** non-missing value for `dyrstr` but has missings also. However, we assigned 1's to it. The first code would assign 0's.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this not exactly what I'm searching for. I don not only want to check whether "the first and last observations coincide for each firm" but I want to checkt whether there are different observations for each firm.

Comment: The _strategy_ uses a check on the first and last observations to conclude if there are different observations for each firm. If there are different observations for a firm, this necessarily implies that the first and last are different. If they are all the same, the first and last are equal. Therefore, this is enough for what you want (if I understand your problem correctly). Note the importance of the `sort`ing. This kind of logic is very useful in Stata, and generally, in any programming language.

Comment: @Roberto Ferrer's approaches matches that at http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/listing-observations-in-group/

Comment: Now, I understand your point! Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

@Roberto Ferrer's excellent answer can be expanded to make explicit what happens with

```
sort firm_id year
by firm_id: gen twodyrstr = 1 if (dyrstr[_n-1] != dyrstr[_n])
```

at the beginning of each panel. For the first such observation, this reduces to

```
by firm_id: gen twodyrstr = 1 if dyrstr[0] != dyrstr[1]
```

It's not a error to refer to any varname[0], but Stata always evaluates that as missing, so

```
dyrstr[0] != dyrstr[1]
```

will be true (evaluates as 1) whenever `dyrstr[1]` is not missing.